# Why is the two-term form for the Cauchy equation sufficient?

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction, wavelength, dispersion

The general Cauchy equation for the relationship between refractive index and wavelength is given by,
$$n = A + \frac{B}{\lambda^{2}}+\frac{C}{\lambda^{4}}+...,$$ 
but this is often approximated to
$$n = A + \frac{B}{\lambda^{2}}.$$
I am unsure as to how this approximation works, because surely for small wavelengths such as those on the visible spectrum the higher-order terms become greater and dominate the equation.

Answer (score 2):

The Cauchy equation is

- empirical,
- an approximation, and
- only ever valid over a restricted interval in wavelength.

You cannot extrapolate it past its range of validity, so if it starts behaving unphysically for small wavelengths or for large wavelengths, then it's because you're using it outside the interval where it is valid.

In particular, it's important to note that Cauchy's equation should **not** be taken as a convergent series. The $\lambda^{-2}$ term works reasonably well to account for the decrease in the refractive index for materials with normal dispersion away from any resonances, and the $\lambda^{-4}$ term can fudge things a bit so that it becomes a bit more accurate, but that's where it stops. If you want to be more accurate, you need a better model which actually takes the physics into account, be it the [Sellmeier equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sellmeier_equation) or something more detailed.

Moreover, that said,

> for small wavelengths such as those on the visible spectrum

the wavelengths in the visible spectrum are not "small" (and neither are they "big"). No quantity with nontrivial physical dimensions (e.g. length) can be said to be "big" or "small" in isolation. For the particular case of the Cauchy equation, the coefficients have different units (so e.g. $[A]=1$ but $[B]=[L^2]$, $[C]=[L^4]$, and so on), and it is the values of those lengths that determines whether $\lambda$ is "big" or "small".

(But, in any case, for the Cauchy equation you'll have $B^{1/2}$, $C^{1/4}$, $\ldots$, take values in the middle of the visible range (and then smaller), so long as that is the interval to which you tuned the empirical fit. As such, visible-light wavelengths will *not* be small, by construction.)